# How can I apply a @media print style to a ckeditor instance?

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I have tried defining a `@media` style in the page as well as the external file that I am passing ckeditor in the config but neither seems to have any effect when I click the print button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

This example (framed) should give you some ideas ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/SKJYT/)):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'toolbar,wysiwygarea,sourcearea,print,basicstyles',
    on: {
        // When CKEditor DOM is loaded, append stuff to <head>.
        contentDom: function() {
            var doc = this.document,
                head = doc.getHead();

            // Via <link> tag.
            doc.createElement( 'link', {
                attributes: {
                    rel: 'stylesheet',
                    type: 'text/css',
                    href: 'print.css',
                    media: 'print'
                }
            } ).appendTo( head );

            // Via <style> tag.
            var style = doc.createElement( 'style', {
                attributes: {
                    type: 'text/css'
                }
            } );

            style.setText( '@media print { * { color: red } }' );

            style.appendTo( head );
        }
    }
} );
```